# API not returning the correct data I want

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, search

I am using an API gem with Rails(https://github.com/games-directory/api-giantbomb) so I can search through data. I got it working, however the data displayed has unnecessary text.

Here is my method that returns the search data:

```
  def index
  @games = GiantBomb::Search.new().query(params[:query]).resources('game').limit(100).fields('name').fetch
  end
```

And it redirects to this page:

```
<ul>
  <% @games.each do |game| %>
    <li><%= game %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

It displays the query data, however the result is something like this:

```
{"name"=>"Kirby Battle Royale", "resource_type"=>"game"}
```

I thought I would just get "Kirby Battle Royale", but it is showing other data as well. I assume this is because each individual "game" is the data being pulled from the search instead. So adding something like game.name doesn't work because the search code doesn't have a specific name attribute.

I looked through the documentation, and I thought @games = GiantBomb::Game.detail(:query) might work but then I get an undefined method for each.

I am not sure how to correctly define @games and where to put my search code.

Comment: Just change `<li><%= game %></li>` to `<li><%= game['name'] %></li>`

Comment: Thanks @engineersmky that worked and I can call other data as well using the game[' '] format.

I am having trouble with images though. According to the documentation the main image is tied to ['image'], but it spits out a list of the image with different size specifications like below:
"icon_url"=>"https://giantbomb1.cbsistatic.com/uploads/square_avatar/0/9536/2964099-3956141630-DJovjfwUEAAfHc4.jpg%3Alarge",
"small_url"=>"https://giantbomb1.cbsistatic.com/uploads/scale_small/0/9536/2964099-3956141630-DJovjfwUEAAfHc4.jpg%3Alarge"

How can I use just one of these to display via img src?

Comment: [Hash Documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D)